# Computer returns to BIOS during Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot

I built a computer a couple days ago, and it's working fine. So far I have (repeatedly) tried to install Ubuntu. Then, either one of three things happen. First, it may return to the BIOS page where it displays "MSI military motherboards, press <kbd>del</kbd> to enter BIOS or <kbd>f11</kbd> to enter boot page-thingy". If it doesn't, then the install starts, or so it seems. The progress bar so far (on any of my attempts) only says "Getting the time from a network time server...", and nothing else. For, like, an hour. And by then it has returned to the MSI BIOS page.